# How to implement MSAL using iOS Touchid and Faceid

Tags: ios, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I am working on Microsoft authentication library for login. Using android and ios libraries i am able to authenticate MicroSoft outlook accounts. In MSAL documentation i couldn't find about TouchID/FaceID. Is there any way to do authentication with TouchID/FaceID.

Comment: Those are local authentication methods; They only authenticate the user on the local device.  If the user has saved their credentials in a password manager such as iCloud Keychain or 1Password then they should be able to use TouchID/FaceID to full those saved credentials into the authentication web form

Comment: I understood, but some libraries provide access token after successful fingerprint authentication and hit the webservice

Comment: You could build that; Store the token in the KeyChain and use TouchId/FaceID to retrieve it next time; You need to determine whether your app needs that level of security.  Personally I prefer if I have unlocked the device and the app has a valid token that it just works without any additional login.